# Why does my while loop in PHP not work?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, binary

```
$number = $_POST['number'];
$colno = 1;
$count = 1;

while ($colno <= $number) {
    $colno = $colno * 2;
    $count++;
}

$count = $count - 1;
$colno = $colno / 2;

echo 'It is ';
echo $count;
echo '-bit(s)';

echo '<br />';


while ($number > 0) {
    if ($colno <= $number) {
        echo '1';
        $number = $number - $colno;
        $colno / 2;
    } else {
        echo '0';
        $colno / 2;
    }
}
```

This is my code, but the while loop at the end does not work and I just wondered why. This happens.

The project is a Binary converter so you can enter a Binary number on the index.php page and that data is then sent to the send.php page (this one the code listed). The send.php page is meant to calculate how many bits of Binary it is and then display that code in Binary.

Once submitted on Google Chrome, it just freezes and loads nothing but the html before the PHP. Once submitted on iPhone on Safari it loads a 1 and then a long list of zeros that do not stop (10000000000000000...).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem. What happened when you tried it? Did you get an error message? Did you get incorrect results? Did you get *no results*? If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect? What were you expecting instead? Did you get *any* correct results? If so, what were they? Don't make us guess.

Comment: Try echoing out $number somewhere and make sure you have what you think you do. Otherwise please explain exactly what about it is not working.

Comment: This line does nothing: `$colno / 2;`. You probably want this instead: `$colno /= 2;`

Comment: Thank you, it was because $colno / 2; did nothing and I have now replaced it with: $colno = $colno / 2;

Comment: `var_dump($number)` will tell you all you need to know... whatever value is in there is **NOT** `> 0`, so the while loop terminates immediately.